# tortoisesvn slow Windows 10

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

After upgrading to Windows 10, a colleague and I, have huge problems using Tortoisesvn, especially the repository browser.

When navigating around in the directories, depending on the content, and amount of files, it usually hangs for about a minute or two.
We diden't have these kind of issues using Windows 7, and the latest version of tortiose.

What we've tried so far is:
Look through all applications that is related to file extentions, this would be a known error when using the repo browser, and windows would try to fetch the program related to the file extention.

Disable IPV6 this would cause problems on some machines.

Updating Windows 10 fully, an update from MS would also solve this cause.

When using the DebugView and enabling debug mode in Tortoise, I can see that the application hangs in the List command, and ReadProperties commands.

We've also tried disabling the firewall, antivirus and so fourth.
When browsing the repository using a browser, there is no speed issues.

Comment: What happens when you run `svn info REPO-URL` in Windows Command Prompt? Is there any delay? Do your computers have access to the Internet? See this article: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00143/

Comment: The speed of the cmd is very fast, it's listed within seconds, the same as if i use the svn link in my browser.. all the computers are on the same network, with access to the same servers